# MySQL script retrieves Steam ID and nothing else

Tags: php, mysql, steam

I have a problem with the Steam Authentication for the web. As you know, Steam provides a script to allow people to connect on your site through the Steam database. My problem is my code only inserts the Steam ID in the database and not the name & avatar.
My code:

```
if (isset($_GET['login'])){
require 'db.php';
require 'openid.php';
require 'userInfo.php';
try {
    require 'SteamConfig.php';

    $openid = new LightOpenID($steamauth['domainname']);

    if(!$openid->mode) {
        $openid->identity = 'http://steamcommunity.com/openid';
        header('Location: ' . $openid->authUrl());
    } elseif ($openid->mode == 'cancel') {
        echo 'User has canceled authentication!';
    } else {
        if($openid->validate()) { 
            $id = $openid->identity;
            $ptn = "/^http:\/\/steamcommunity\.com\/openid\/id\/(7[0-9]{15,25}+)$/";
            preg_match($ptn, $id, $matches);

            $_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];

                $sql_fetch_id = "SELECT * FROM member WHERE steamid = '".$_SESSION['steamid']."'";
                $query_id = mysqli_query($db, $sql_fetch_id);

                if (mysqli_num_rows($query_id) == 0) {
                    $sql_steam = "INSERT INTO member (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('".$_SESSION['personaname']."', '".$_SESSION['steamid']."', '".$_SESSION['avatar']."')";
                    mysqli_query($db, $sql_steam);
                }

            if (!headers_sent()) {
                header('Location: '.$steamauth['loginpage']);
                exit;
            } else {
                ?>
                <script type="text/javascript">
                    window.location.href="<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>";
                </script>
                <noscript>
                    <meta http-   equiv="refresh" content="0;url=<?=$steamauth['loginpage']?>" />
                </noscript>
                <?php
                exit;
            }

            } else {
            echo "User is not logged in.\n";
        }
    }
} catch(ErrorException $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
 }
```

Screenshot
[image: screenshot]

Comment: Everthing before `$_SESSION['steamid'] = $matches[1];` would help to help you. You are not showing relevant code. SQL's are OK. But are the `_SESSION` data always set correct? Did you dump the SQL before querying it, to see how it looks like?

Comment: Do a `var_dump($_SESSION)` and check if it contains what you think it does.

Comment: code updated!  now you can see the 60% of the code

Comment: Here its the dump, all value NULL, only steamid work.. { ["steam_steamid"]=> NULL ["steam_communityvisibilitystate"]=> NULL ["steam_profilestate"]=> NULL ["steam_personaname"]=> NULL ["steam_lastlogoff"]=> NULL ["steam_profileurl"]=> NULL ["steam_avatar"]=> NULL ["steam_avatarmedium"]=> NULL ["steam_avatarfull"]=> NULL ["steam_personastate"]=> NULL ["steam_realname"]=> string(19) "Real name not given" ["steam_primaryclanid"]=> NULL ["steam_timecreated"]=> NULL ["steam_uptodate"]=> int(1485789213) ["steamid"]=> string(17) "7372792947" }

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the output of `var_dump($_SESSION)` (which should be in the question) it seems as if you're not actually referencing the keys of the session correctly.

With this line of code:

```
$sql_steam = "INSERT INTO member (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('".$_SESSION['personaname']."', '".$_SESSION['steamid']."', '".$_SESSION['avatar']."')";
```

You're referencing `$_SESSION['personaname']`, however, only `['steam_personaname']` is provided in the session. So you're referencing something that isn't there.

So you should be using:

```
$sql_steam = "INSERT INTO member (name, steamid, avatar) VALUES  ('".$_SESSION['steam_personaname']."', '".$_SESSION['steamid']."', '".$_SESSION['steam_avatarfull']."')";
```

Comment: the problem remains

Comment: With the var_dump you created, is that the actual data you're working with? Because the data for `steam_personaname` is NULL in your example.

Comment: and if I refresh the page,  from null it update to the right value.. if you can see steamid is not null without page refresh